# Sum over greatest integer

Tags: riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Evaluate ${\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{n}{2}]} \cos \left(\frac{ kπ}{n}\right)}$

I think it is Riemann sum of some integral like $\int_{0}^{1} \cos (πx) \,dx ,$
but how to approach for the upper limit of summation?

Comment: The answer should be $\frac{1}{\pi}$. You can get an explicit value for the summation through [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fn+cos%28kpi%2Fn%29+from+k%3D1+to+k%3DRound%28n%2F2%29) and taking the limit (or plotting the graph on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lpwblklwly)) gives the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

This limit can be changed to an Integral$$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{[n/2]}  \cos \left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)= \int_{0}^{1/2} cos (\pi x) dx= 
\frac{1}{\pi}. $$

Comment: Won't greatest integer make any change here?

Comment: When $n \rightarrow \infty$, it the integer and integer-part do not make adifference.